# Apache CXF 2.6.6, ReceiveTimeout, new endpoint

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf

Hi I have a problem with change ReceiveTimeout, and setup new endpoint
I have a code:

to change the endpoint I'm using code:

```
Map<String, Object> prop = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
prop.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint);
```

and change timeout :

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = http.getClient();
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
```

but this is doesn't work

the last part is setup ReceiveTimeout but for default endpoit.

I use server jboss 6.1

How to change ReceiveTimeout for new endpoint ??